# Seamless transition from UIImagePickerController to a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I got a `UIViewController` where I have a button which opens a `UIImagePickerController`.

What I want to achieve is a *seamless* transition from my `UIImagePickerController` to a second `UIViewController`.

I tried that

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toSecondVC", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

I also tried

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
        let secondView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondView")
        self.presentViewController(secondView!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Both give me the same result which is basically that when I close the `UIImagePickerController`, it displays the first view controller during a very short moment and then does the transition to the second view controller.

How to get rid of that short moment displaying the first view controller?